# Should I standardize the second datset with the same scaling as in the first dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, scaling, transfer-learning, standardization

I am in very much confusion.

I have two datasets. One dataset is considered a source domain (Dataset A) and other dataset is considered a target domain (Dataset B).

**First,** I standardized each column of Dataset A using mean and standard deviation value of respective columns. I have 600 points in the dataset A. Then I splitted my dataset into Training, Validation and Testing dataset. I trained CNN model and then I tested model using testing dataset. I gives pretty accurate results (prediction).

I have calculated `mean` and `standard deviation` of each column available in `Dataset A` as follow,

```
thicknessMean = np.mean(thick_SD)
MaxForceMean = np.mean(maxF_SD)
MeanForceMean = np.mean(meanF_SD)

thicknessstd = np.std(thick_SD)
MaxForcestd = np.std(maxF_SD)
MeanForcestd = np.std(meanF_SD)

thick_SD_scaled = (thick_SD - thicknessMean)/thicknessstd
maxF_SD_scaled = (maxF_SD - MaxForceMean)/MaxForcestd
meanF_SD_scaled = (meanF_SD - MeanForceMean)/MeanForcestd
```

**Now,** I want to make prediction from the model by feeding the Dataset B. Therefore, I saved the already trained model (with .pth file). Then I standardize the dataset B, but this time I have transformed the dataset using 'mean' and 'standard deviation' of the dataset A. After doing this, I evaluate the already trained model using dataset B. But it is giving a worse prediction.

```
thick_TD_scaled = (thick_TD - thicknessMean)/thicknessstd
maxF_TD_scaled = (maxF_TD - MaxForceMean)/MaxForcestd
meanF_TD_scaled = (meanF_TD - MeanForceMean)/MeanForcestd
```

You can see, to scale my dataset B, I have used mean value for eg.`thicknessMean` and standard deviation for eg. `thicknessstd` value of the Dataset A .

**My question is:**

(1) where I am doing wrong? What should I do to make my prediction near to accurate?

(2) When I check prediction's accuracy on two different dataset, should I standardize the second dataset at a same scaling as in the first dataset?

Comment: You have to add at least few lines of your datasets, or few lines or code that better explain qhat you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for reminding. It would have been better if you had told me before marking this question for close. Kindly see my updated question. I think it will help you getting an idea of the problem. I am looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: It wasn't me who marked it, I'm sorry

Comment: ah..then I am sorry..It will be helpful if you give me your opinion on my question